# Cannot connect in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

[image: oracleSQLdeveloper]

I have a problem with just installed Oracle SQL Developer. In the column 'Connections' I don't have any button to add connection and there is no possibility to connect in the other way. I used the SQL Developer before and I have never had a problem like that.

Comment: Something is wrong with your install. You might need to delete it and reextract from the zip...or delete your system20.4... directory under AppData

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you don't have any buttons, but - you do have the "File" menu which lets you choose "New" and "Connection".

BTW, I hope you also have a database to connect to; SQL Developer itself doesn't install any database.

Comment: Yes but when I open New and try to connet nothing happen, I also try Create a Connection Manually and I've installed Oracle Databese 19c

Comment: Maybe something went wrong during *installation*. Remove SQL Developer, download fresh installation files and start over.

Comment: I did it earlier

Comment: Which operating system do you use?

Comment: Also, which version of Java is installed on your machine? (if you're not using the Windows release packaged with Java)

Answer (score 0):

to solve the problem in windows follow following step

1.first  install oracle software and sqldeveloper  saperately and have same versions.

type about your pc in search bar

find device name

then go into homes folder which created in user name folder .local disk c>app>james>product>21c>homes>oradb21home1>network>admin>listner file

change host name to device name and save it.

come into sqldeveloper app and while creating the new connection ,change localhost name to device name.

app will work

Comment: More wordy answer it would be good if provided the screenshot and some examples around.